# How can I switch between 2 different applications on Appium test?

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I have an Appium test script that is written in java which access my application on android.

On the script, I start my application main activity and then move to the second activity, then I switch to the device Messages application and then wish to return to the second activity of my application.

I tried several ways but I always return to the main activity of my application.

Any idea how can I switch back from the device Messages App to the second activity of my application?

Thanks

Comment: Please share code which you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved.

I used the AndroidDriver methods .navigate().back()

Answer (score 0):

You can use the device hardware back button to navigate back to the previous application.

driver.navigate().back();

but still its not possible to navigate back to the application.